# geomesa ingest command not working

Tags: accumulo, geomesa

I am setting up environments for geomesa-accumulo data store and trying to ingest feature using csv file by creating sfts and converters in respective reference.conf file. However when I run command

```
geomesa ingest -u root -p mypassword -c ajjas -i jarvis -s ajjas_pings -C ajjas_pings-csv data/ajjas_test_data/ajjas-result
```

execution never gets finished and shows

```
suresh@hpss-MacBook-Air:~/geomesa-accumulo_2.11-1.3.0 $ geomesa ingest -u root -p 9869547580 -c ajjas -i jarvis -s ajjas_pings -C ajjas_pings-csv data/ajjas_test_data/ajjas-result
Using GEOMESA_ACCUMULO_HOME = /Users/suresh/geomesa-accumulo_2.11-1.3.0
INFO  Creating schema ajjas_pings
```

I am not able to understand what is going wrong. The same happens if am trying to delete existing schemas or features. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get more info about what is going on, there are two options:

1. Check the logs in logs/geomesa.log.
2. Find the PID of the running ingest command use 'jstack' to see what the JVM is doing.  One of the threads is likely trying to communicate with Accumulo, and that stack trace will provide lots of help.

In terms of causes, this can help when...

a.  there is a mismatch of Accumulo versions between the GeoMesa bundle and the Accumulo installation

b.  GeoMesa cannot get a distributed lock as it creates tables (the underlying issue may be related to Zookeeper, etc)

c.  various networking issues.  For instance, Accumulo is running in Docker or VM images, the hostnames used for zookeeper and the hostnames in the Accumulo services config files ($ACCUMULO_HOME/conf/{master,gc,slaves,monitor,tservers}) can matter.

A big note is that the machine where the GeoMesa ingest is running needs to be able to communicate to all the tablet servers.